# NTP time sync service on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm architecting infrastructure via AWS.

To deploy docker-compose, I used ECS.

For resolve time sync issue, I found some interesting article. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html)

It looks very simple if just launch EC2 instance.

After read that article, I found some issue on my case.

Docker container is running on EC2 instance.

So, I just set NTP to my EC2 instance only?

Or, have to set NTP for my docker container too?

I can't find any document related this issue.

Any suggestion, will be a lot of help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [How to make sure docker's time syncs with that of the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551592/how-to-make-sure-dockers-time-syncs-with-that-of-the-host)

Docker containers are sharing the same kernel as their host. A clock drift can not happen. To keep the container on time you just need to keep the host on time.