# AWS S3 - Access denied , Request is not yet valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to show a private file from S3, so i am generating S3 sign URL, but when I open url in the browser i get this,

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request is not yet valid</Message>
<X-Amz-Date>1559667828000</X-Amz-Date>
<Expires>2019-06-04T17:08:46Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2019-06-04T04:38:30Z</ServerTime>
<RequestId>BCB52dF0973D5E20</RequestId>
<HostId>********************************************</HostId>
</Error>
```

I do not understand what is the problem, can anyone explain this error.

Code for generating signed url

```
 GetPreSignedUrlRequest request1 = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
    {
      BucketName = bucketName,
      Key = "key",
      Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
    };
   urlString = client.GetPreSignedURL(request1);
```

Comment: how are you generating S3 Signed URL and are you adding any expiry to it  ?

Comment: Yes, for 5 minutes.

Comment: It appears that your code to generate the pre-signed URL is not working correctly. Can you show us the code? You can also test it by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) [`aws s3 presign` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html).

Comment: Is your local timezone/date correct?

Comment: @WalterA thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your local pc timezone is not correct.

Your local pc should have same date time zone as per region of bucket for which you are generating signed url.

Comment: Thanks for saving my day. I have corrected time zone of my PC and now its working  :)

Comment: In my case the problem was that I was running a MinIO in a Docker container on Windows using the WSL 2 backend. The WSL clock was hanging behind the system clock after I put my laptop to sleep - only a restart of Windows helped.

Comment: Moritz's comment explains my situation as well. Luckily, I recently came across a solution that doesn't require a Windows restart. `docker run --rm --privileged alpine hwclock -s` Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55245963/5984310