# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, pip, environment

I was trying to install some python packages as I normally do, and got the following warning and error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7ffaa13b1250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /packages/4e/5f/528232275f6509b1fff703c9280e58951a81abe24640905de621c9f81839/pip-20.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

This warning shows up 5 times, and finally the error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/4e/5f/528232275f6509b1fff703c9280e58951a81abe24640905de621c9f81839/pip-20.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7ffaa1423610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')
```

I tried also to upgrade my pip with `python -m install --upgrade pip` and got the same exact output.
I saw similar SO posts that suggest using this command `pip install --user <package_name>` but that wouldn't work for me - I get the same error.

I also tried using different environments and different paths but the output is the same.

OS is linux.

EDIT: I didn't do anything, just tried to install the packages again after a few hours and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when running inside a Docker container, due to the [Docker not syncing with the host machine's clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551592/how-to-make-sure-dockers-time-syncs-with-that-of-the-host) bug

It was fixed by fixing that error, by running `docker run --rm --privileged alpine hwclock -s`