# Keycloak returning already-expired tokens

Tags: jwt, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid, access-token

I'm trying to use keycloak to get access tokens,

but I get the error `Token is expired` when trying to use the tokens issued by keycloak

For example, if I get a token using curl:

```sh
curl -u account:___mysecret___ -k
-d "grant_type=password&username=testuser&password=__some__pass"
-H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/testRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

and decode the returned token using jwt.io, I can see that the exp date is yesterday's date.

how do I get usable access tokens?

Comment: Do you have wrong time on your localhost?

Comment: @JanGaraj maybe. It's running in docker. But I had to restart the computer due to other reasons, and after that the time was ok.

Comment: there is the solution describe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086856/wsl2-clock-is-out-of-sync-with-windows

Answer (score 3):

I think you were using keycloak with docker desktop on windows.

And your localtime of your hyperV where not synchronize anymore with your host computer.

If you wrote : date   in your docker container, the date is wrong.

So the token genreate by keycloak was outdated

So rebooting hyperV resynchronize the localtime in your docker container.

More info here : [How to make sure docker's time syncs with that of the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551592/how-to-make-sure-dockers-time-syncs-with-that-of-the-host)

Answer (score 0):

Checked in the "realm settings" the "tokens" tab! There you can configure session timeout and token validity.

Further check in "clients" => "settings" => "advanced settings" if there is set something.

Then please check the time and time zone configured on you keycloak host.

Comment: had to restart the computer (for another reason) and after that keycloak continued working fine.