# error building docker image 'executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update]'

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to build a docker image but it throws an error and I can't seem to figure out why.

It is stuck at `RUN apt-get -y update` with the following error messages:

```
4.436 E: Release file for http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2d 16h 26min 22s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

4.436 E: Release file for http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3d 10h 28min 24s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update]: exit code: 100
```

Here's my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.7

# Adding trusting keys to apt for repositories
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
# Adding Google Chrome to the repositories
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
# Updating apt to see and install Google Chrome
RUN apt-get -y update
# Magic happens
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# Installing Unzip
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
# Download the Chrome Driver
RUN CHROMEDRIVER_RELEASE=$(curl http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) && \
    echo "Chromedriver latest version: $CHROMEDRIVER_RELEASE" && \
    wget --quiet "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_RELEASE/chromedriver_linux64.zip" && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    rm -rf chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver && \
    chromedriver --version
# Set display port as an environment variable
ENV DISPLAY=:99

WORKDIR /

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN pip install -e .
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Either your local  is not setup correctly or a server has bad data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's answered here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059217/getting-release-is-not-valid-yet-while-updating-ubuntu-docker-container

> Correct your system clock. (in comments I also suggested checking for a mismatch between clock and your timezone too)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved it for me. For anyone coming here in the future, here's how to sync the clock between docker and the host for Windows users: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65203691/8353218

Answer (score 20):

In my case, docker was still using the cached `RUN apt update && apt upgrade` command, thus not updating the package sources.

The solution was to build the docker image once with the `--no-cache` flag:

```
docker build --no-cache .
```

Comment: Just a note for people finding this - it's generally recommended to combine apt commands into one `RUN` command e.g. `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...`. That way you avoid an old invocation of `update` being cached, and a later `install` command failing due to a missing package. https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#apt-get

Answer (score 6):

If you are using docker desktop, please check if enough resources are set in settings/preferences.
Eg. memory and disk requirement

Comment: Could you suggest commands to clean up unused containers etc.. to free up resources.

Comment: Please refer
https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/ OR 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images

Answer (score 2):

I get this `ERROR: executor failed running [...]: exit code: 100` error message when I mistyped the name of a package.

This was in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN sudo apt-get update; \
    sudo apt-get -y upgrade; \
    sudo apt-get install -y gnupg2 wget lsb_release
```

instead of this:

```
RUN sudo apt-get update; \
    sudo apt-get -y upgrade; \
    sudo apt-get install -y gnupg2 wget lsb-release
```

(see the difference between the underscore and the dash.)

Fixing the package name solved the problem.

Comment: thanks - tripped me up as I added this last week.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding the `-y` flag to apt-get install e.g.

```
apt-get -y install git
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens specific to OS also.

I had same issues running MariaDB on my Windows 10.

Check for Docker Settings:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": false,
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  },
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "enabled": true,
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB"
    }
  }
}
```

**Remove below block, and it should work:**

```
"features": {
    "buildkit": true
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and I think it was because I installed `buildx` but the version of the plugin didn't match my docker installation. Uninstalling buildx resolved the issue for me:

```
docker buildx uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

For me adding this to the Dockerfile did the job:

```
RUN apk add --update linux-headers;
```