# Updated Docker; now Docker exits with "failed to solve" error / code 100

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

Dang, what on earth has happened to Docker. With no code changes, after updating recently it's not playing havoc for me. Here's my Compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  # web service (connected to local DB)
  web: &web
    container_name: web
    env_file: .env
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 2G
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: /bin/sh -c "rm -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid && gem install bundler -v 2.2.21 && bundle install && rails db:migrate && rails server --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 5432:5432
      - 2222:2222
    volumes:
      - ../:/app:cached
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - db
    profiles:
      - app
      - appnm

  # database
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:14.2
    volumes:
      - .psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
      - dbdat:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./log:/root/log:cached
      - ./hlp-db.dump:/hlp-db.dump
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB
      - POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - 5432
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1
      interval: 5s
    profiles:
      - app
      - appnm
      - db

  # database admin
  db-admin:
    container_name: dbAdmin
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - 1933:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
    profiles:
      - app
      - appnm
      - db

volumes:
  web:
  bundle:
  dbdat:
  node_modules:
  rails_cache:
```

And here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.4
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
ENV APP_HOME /app
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
EXPOSE 3000
```

Here's the error:

```
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential]: exit code: 100
```

And finally here's the command I ran:

```
docker compose --profile appnm up -d
```

As I say, this exact setup worked fine before updating Docker recently - the command it's complaining about hasn't changed. Anyone any idea what's up?

MAny thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error building docker image 'executor failed running \[/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66008106/error-building-docker-image-executor-failed-running-bin-sh-c-apt-get-y-upda)

Comment: Most likely related to daylight savings changing and not related to Docker being updated. Clear your docker cache with `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) ; docker rmi $(docker images -q) ; docker builder prune --all --force` if you continue to have problems after reading the linked duplicate.