# PHP shows time with 20 minute difference

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone

I'm using PHP 7.4.24 on docker env. In php ini I specified only time zone:

```
[Date]
date.timezone = Japan
```

Even if you specify the time zone inside the script it doesn't matter

```
$date = new \DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Japan'));
echo $date->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
```

It says:
10.11.2021 14:14:17, but real time for that timezone for now is 10.11.2021 17:34:17
My biggest issue is that the time difference is 20 minutes, so I can't pick other timezone to make it work correct.

Comment: Shouldn't `date.timezone = Japan` be `date.timezone=Asia/Tokyo` ?

Comment: Is the server time correct?

Comment: @bassxzero, "Japan" - is valid time zone, but even if I specify "Asia/Tokyo" - the time difference is still 20 min.

Comment: @droopsnoot, it's in docker container. It should take time&date from the host. How can I check it?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in this question
[How to make sure docker's time syncs with that of the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551592/how-to-make-sure-dockers-time-syncs-with-that-of-the-host)
I ran this in console and it helped

```
docker run --rm --privileged alpine hwclock -s
```