# Docker container have independent time from host system

Tags: linux, docker, time

I have an application that needs apache to report the same year in the past otherwise it will not work correct (it's encoded with ioncube so I cannot change the code). I configured it as a service and set it to run in a docker container. If i set the docker container date using date --set="" it will not allow me, then i set the privileged: true in the Docker file and it works but as soon as i set to it goes back to the default date (in the host system i have a time sync function that kicks in). I would like the host system to have it's real time but inside the container to be able to set a date in the past. How can I do that ? Thanks

Both host and the container are Debian 11.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551592/how-to-make-sure-dockers-time-syncs-with-that-of-the-host

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/824631/how-to-set-system-time-dynamically-in-a-docker-container