# AWS cannot validate the provided access credentials (eclipse)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, credentials, aws-sdk

I have been working with the AWS SDK for Java to start an amazon EC2 instance through a simple Java program. I have provided my secret and access key in the code itself, and in `windows>preferences>aws sdk` also. I've also added my credentials to the key I am using. And I am still getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 401; Error Code: AuthFailure; Request ID: cc82e725-5a8a-44d8-9f7c-2031d6db1e1a)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:11819)
at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.startInstances(AmazonEC2Client.java:6153)
at amazon.Amazon.main(Amazon.java:53)
```

Here is my Java  Code

```
 package amazon;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.StartInstancesRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.StartInstancesResult;

public class Amazon 
{
static AmazonEC2 ec2;

    static void authentication() throws Exception {
    AWSCredentials credentials=null;
 credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("****","****");
 credentials=new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();

    System.out.println("Credentials : " + credentials);
    ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
    Region region=Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1);
    ec2.setRegion(region);

}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
      authentication(); 
        StartInstancesRequest startInstancesRequest = new StartInstancesRequest();

             startInstancesRequest.withInstanceIds("i-sba78aj1");

   StartInstancesResult res = ec2.startInstances(startInstancesRequest); 
              System.out.println(res.toString());
              return;
      }
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Perhaps not a good question.. Are you able to login directly?

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744205/ec2-api-error-validating-access-credential Sounds like a similar problem and has an interesting solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is some confusion in your program - when you do :

```
AWSCredentials credentials=null;
credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("****","****");
credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
```

the line `credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("****","****");` is finally not necessary, as credentials will be set and after replaced with the one from the ProfileCredentialsProvider.

You cannot use at the same time the `BasicAWSCredentials` and the `ProfileCredentialsProvider`

When you use `ProfileCredentialsProvider` you need to have a valid credential file under `~/.aws/credentials` the file should be in the form

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXX
```

In this case you'll do

```
    AWSCredentials credentials = null;
    try {
        credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                e);
    }
    AmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
```

If you do not use the credential file, you can create the credentials from API from the `BasicAWSCredentials` as you did:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXX", "XXXXX");
// no need to call the ProfileCredentialsProvider in this case
ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
```

*Just a simple note*, I understand you might run a quick test and you make it work from a main method, but really declaring `static AmazonEC2 ec2;` is a bad practice, the EC2Client should not be static. (in simple program it can be alright but as your infrastructure is growing (multiple region, instances ...) , it is just not possible)

Comment: What should I use.. if not static?

Comment: normal variable and declare a constructor to initialize the variable and a get method to retrieve the variable