# Any way to make linux system time go faster?

Tags: docker, system-clock

I'm working on an application related to time. In order to simulate a real environment, I needed to adjust the system clock of a virtual machine 1440 times faster (one day became one minute) during testing.

My application actually runs in a docker container, and I tried using [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime) to speed up my container clock, and it worked. But the problem is that I have multiple containers that need to synchronize their time, which seems difficult to do.

Since this is a test environment, multiple containers are running on one VM through docker-compose, so can I just speed up the system clock of the VM? How can we do this?

Comment: If libfaketime worked inside a docker container, does it work in the VM?

Comment: Containers use the same kernel, and the same time, as their host system; you can't independently change the time in a container without changing the entire system's clock.  (Some answers seem to talk about time _zones_, but that's not the same thing.)  See for example [Creating clock skew with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432395/creating-clock-skew-with-docker).

Comment: This is a very dumb idea, I assure you, but one potential option, if being off by up to 2.4 minutes is fine, is to run an NTP server which runs 1440 times faster, and then run `watch -n 0.1 (command to sync NTP)` on the client to synchronize the clock with the NTP server 10 times a second. Again, this is a very dumb idea, but if you're fine with some hackery, then this might be the easiest solution. As far as I can tell there is no existing NTP server that supports time travel, but I can't imagine it's very difficult to write an NTP server. But again, this is a *very* dumb "solution".

Comment: Got something actually useful this time: You can sync between libfaketime different processes by storing the time in a file - see [libfaketime issue #21](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime/issues/321). But I wasn't able to get this to work, unfortunately.