# How does Hotspot JVM determine exactly the current timezone on Linux(Centos)?

Tags: java, linux, date, jvm, docker

I have a problem when the current timezone is not determined correctly in a JVM instance running inside a Docker container (both host and container are Cent OS 6.5).

First of all I have mapped `etc/localtime` to the child container via `-v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro` (I think it's a [prevalent way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800624/will-docker-container-auto-sync-time-with-the-host-machine))

When I login via SSH both on host and container

> date -u

prints
`Mon Apr 20 11:48:57 UTC 2015`

and

> date

prints
`Mon Apr 20 14:50:41 MSK 2015`

In JVM  however with

> System.out.println(new Date());

I get `Mon Apr 20 11:52:24 UTC 2015` inside container and `Mon Apr 20 14:53:17 MSK 2015` inside the host.

How is the current timezone determined exactly?

[Oracle FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/dst-faq-138158.html#patches) did not shed the light, I don't quite understand what metrics Java does Java use to get timezone for the current user

> Do my operating system's timezone patches fix the Java platform's
> timezone data?
>
> No. The Java SE platform's timezone data is not read
> from the local or host operating system. The Java SE platform
> maintains a private repository of timezone data in locally installed
> files ( .../jre/lib/zi) as part of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE)
> software. Applying whatever operating system timezone patches (for
> example Solaris OS, Linux, Windows) will have no effect on the
> accuracy of the Java SE platform's timezone data.

**update:** if someone is interested in workaround - I've specified TZ environment variable as in Stephen's answer, so now the container is created with parameters

> -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -e "TZ=Europe/Moscow"

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://minaret.biz/tips/timezone.html), a JVM running on Linux uses the TZ environment variable to give it the name of the local time zone.

The page goes on to explain that TZ is normally set in "/etc/profile", and it doesn't work if Java is launched using a mechanism that doesn't "source" that file.

---

The timezone data that the Oracle FAQ refers to is something different.  It is the data that the JVM uses to map from timezone names to the corresponding zone offsets (taking account of daylight saving adjustments, etcetera).

Comment: Yes - setting TZ works, however it's mystery why the time is different when TZ is not not set - I'll try to inspect TimeZone.setDefaultZone() in spare time.

Comment: I imagine that TZ is set on the host, and not set in the container, and the JVM behaviour if TZ is unset is to assume UTC.