# how to set timezone of 'docker logs -t'?

Tags: linux, docker

My local timezone and docker container's timezone are all set to 'GMT+8:00'. But the 'docker logs -t' still shows timestamp of 'GMT+0:00'.

the picture below is a part of output of 'docker logs -t'. The left timestamp is printed by docker, and the right timestamp is printed by application in container.
[image]

Comment: What is running in that container? Basically you would need to configure the correct timezone in the program, which is running there

Comment: @MichaelAltenburger A web service. The program's timezone is correct (see the right timestamp in the picture). The left timestamp is printed by `-t` option ( `docker logs -t` ) which is wrong, and it seems whatever I configured in container can not affect that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some research, I found out that the `docker logs -t` command prints out timestamps in UTC and there is no config to change that. However, you could use a little script referenced in https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/604, where you could just pipe the output and change the given timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

**update:** it was considered to be a bug and will be fixed

That's weird but log timestamps are handled differently depending on the logging driver used (at the moment I've tested with version 24.0.7 bundled with Ubuntu). The default `json-file` driver stream logs with UTC timestamps, whereas `local` driver stream logs with timestamps aligned to local timezone:

json-file:

```
$ docker run -it --log-driver json-file --name json-file pinger/pinger
...
$ docker logs --timestamps json-file
2023-12-08T11:36:36.545515094Z PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
2023-12-08T11:36:36.546421995Z 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.016 ms
2023-12-08T11:36:37.554829574Z 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
2023-12-08T11:36:38.579084549Z 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
2023-12-08T11:36:39.603001516Z 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
```

local:

```
$ docker run -it --log-driver local --name local pinger/pinger
...
$ docker logs --timestamps local
2023-12-08T06:37:37.036028180-05:00 PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
2023-12-08T06:37:37.036354080-05:00 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
2023-12-08T06:37:38.066921683-05:00 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
2023-12-08T06:37:39.094662180-05:00 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.025 ms
2023-12-08T06:37:40.114650370-05:00 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
```

Given that local driver also used to show logs when any non-local driver is used (i.e. syslog), timestamps should be aligned to local timezone in that case too.