# Docker VM time is not the host OS time

Tags: docker

I've followed installation docs in http://docs.drone.io/installation/

Below is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '2'
services:
 drone-server:
  image: drone/drone:0.8

 ports:
  - 80:8000
  - 9000
 volumes:
  - /var/lib/drone:/var/lib/drone/
 restart: always
 environment:
  - DRONE_OPEN=true
  - DRONE_HOST= localhost
  - DRONE_GITLAB=true
  - DRONE_GITLAB_CLIENT=dfsdfsdf
  - DRONE_GITLAB_SECRET=dsfdsf
  - DRONE_GITLAB_URL=https://tecgit01.com
  - DRONE_SECRET=${DRONE_SECRET}

drone-agent:
 image: drone/agent:0.8

 restart: always
 depends_on:
   - drone-server
 volumes:
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
 environment:
  - DRONE_SERVER=drone-server:9000
  - DRONE_SECRET=${DRONE_SECRET}
```

I'm running this on OSX(10.13.1) with Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4.

Local time in drone_agent is very different from the host time. This is causing the AWS API calls to fail when building my app. It throws this error.https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=103764#. I tried logging the current time inside the app to verify the time difference.

Is there a config to sync host time with the docker agent?

Comment: This has the fix : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800624/will-docker-container-auto-sync-time-with-the-host-machine/38133871#38133871

Answer (score 1):

As you've pointed out, this isn't a Drone.io issue, it's instead an issue with the underlying VM running docker's clock becoming out of sync.

This can be fixed by following the [steps outlined in the question you linked to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800624/will-docker-container-auto-sync-time-with-the-host-machine/38133871#38133871)