# FaunaDB: Timed out waiting for appliedTimestamp for key to reach target

Tags: faunadb

My FaunaDB docker dev node recently started timing out in response to any request, with error messages like `Read timed out. (Timed out waiting for appliedTimestamp for key 6(323942845125755392) to reach 2022-02-25T13:10:03.913Z)`.

My guess is that this has something to do with a desynchronization between the fauna instance's clock and the system clock. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Can you provide the faunadb docker image version and machine info?  Also, can you think of anything in particular that might have triggered the errors, for example had the machine gone to sleep?

Comment: Are you running Fauna Dev on macOS? There appears to be a known issue with clock drift on that platform. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800624/will-a-docker-container-auto-sync-time-with-its-host-machine

Comment: Yep, it was on macos. It seems that removing and recreating the faunadb docker instance solved the problem for now.