# Docker to Docker NTP Synchronisation

Tags: docker, ntp

I use [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/cturra/ntp) Docker image to create a dockerized NTP server.
The goal is to set other Dockers to sync their clocks with the time provided by the first Docker.

The script below starts openntpd client inside the client Dockers.

```
FROM alpine:3.14
RUN apk update && \
apk upgrade && \
rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN apk add openntpd tzdata --no-cache

ADD scripts/ntpd.conf /etc/ntpd.conf
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//' /etc/ntpd.conf
CMD ["ntpd", "-v" ,"-d" ,"-f", "/etc/ntpd.conf"]
```

In order to test, I tried to change the timezone of the server docker to see if 'date' command reflects the change inside the client Docker. It does not.

- First of all, is there a way to force Docker client time to be retrieved by an NTP server or do I have to change the host time as well?
- Is changing the timezone on the server Docker going to affect the response I get when I run 'date' on the client docker? If not, is there a way to test NTP synchronization on alpine linux since all services such as ntpdate and ntpstat are not available?

Comment: Containers share their host system's clock.  You don't need to run ntpd in a container (and might not be able to).  All containers will have the same time, and it should match the host time (but if you're using a VM-based solution like Docker Desktop it might not).  See for example [Will a docker container auto sync time with its host machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800624/will-a-docker-container-auto-sync-time-with-its-host-machine) (but note that its answers tend to confuse the current time and the effective time zone).

Comment: I do need to sync dockers by ntp and not by their individual system clocks.

Comment: Containers don't have individual system clocks.

Comment: By individual system clocks, I was referring to the one they get from their host but given that I do not want to change the host system time, what I'm trying to do might not be possible. A docker cannot sync its 'system' time from an NTP because it gets its time from the host and this behavior cannot be changed?